# Polynomials in Fourier trigonometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, special-functions, fourier-series

I'm successively integrating $x^{n} \cos{k x}$ for increasing values of positive integer n. I'm finding:

$\frac{\sin{kx}}{k}$,

$\frac{\cos{kx}}{k^2}+\frac{x\sin{kx}}{k}$,

$\frac{2 x \cos{kx}}{k^2}+\frac{\left(-2+k^2 x^2\right)sin{kx}}{k^3}$,

$\frac{3 \left(-2+k^2 x^2\right) \cos{kx}}{k^4}+\frac{x \left(-6+k^2 x^2\right) \sin(kx)}{k^3}$

Is there a name for the sequence of polynomials: $x$, $2x$, $k^2x^2-2$, $3(k^2x^2-2)$, $x(k^2x^2-6)$ ... ?

Here is more:

$\frac{\sin{kx}}{k}$

$\frac{\cos{kx}}{k^2}+\frac{x \sin{kx}}{k}$

$\frac{2 x \cos{kx}}{k^2}+\frac{\left(-2+k^2 x^2\right) \sin{kx}}{k^3}$

$\frac{3 \left(-2+k^2 x^2\right) \cos{kx}}{k^4}+\frac{x \left(-6+k^2 x^2\right) \sin{kx}}{k^3}$

$\frac{4 x \left(-6+k^2 x^2\right) \cos{kx}}{k^4}+\frac{\left(24-12 k^2 x^2+k^4 x^4\right) \sin{kx}}{k^5}$

$\frac{5 \left(24-12 k^2 x^2+k^4 x^4\right) \cos{kx}}{k^6}+\frac{x \left(120-20 k^2 x^2+k^4 x^4\right) \sin{kx}}{k^5}$

$\frac{6 x \left(120-20 k^2 x^2+k^4 x^4\right) \cos{kx}}{k^6}+\frac{\left(-720+360 k^2 x^2-30 k^4 x^4+k^6 x^6\right) \sin{kx}}{k^7}$

Comment: They look a bit like Hermite polynomials.

Comment: They don't seem to be exactly Hermite polynomials :-)

Comment: Indeed, but for $k=2$ it might be a good place to start your search.

Comment: Is there a website for sequences of polynomials like OEIS: http://oeis.org/?

Comment: I did some search but didn't turn up anything. It doesn't seem to be an interesting sequence of polynomials, even for k = 2.

Answer (score 4):

The polynomials are recursive in nature, and this behavior is most apparent when the given integral

$$
\int x^n \cos(k x)\,dx
$$

is viewed as the real part of the function

$$
F_{n,k}(x) = \int x^n e^{i k x}\,dx = \int x^n \cos(k x)\,dx + i\!\int x^n \sin(k x)\,dx.
$$

Using integration by parts twice we can derive an inhomogeneous recurrence relation for these functions,

$$
k^2 F_{n,k}(x) - i k (n-1) F_{n-1,k}(x) + (n-1) F_{n-2,k}(x) = e^{i k x}\left(x^{n-1}-i k x^n\right).
\tag{1}
$$

Here we can define the polynomials

$$
P_{n,k}(x) = k^{n+1} e^{-i k x} F_{n,k}(x),
$$

and then use $(1)$ to derive their recurrence relation

$$
P_{n,k}(x) - i (n-1) P_{n-1,k}(x) + (n-1) P_{n-2,k}(x) = (kx)^{n-1} - i (kx)^n.
\tag{2}
$$

Now, if we write

$$
k^{n+1} \int x^n \cos(k x)\,dx = A_{n,k}(x) \cos(kx) - B_{n,k}(x) \sin(kx),
$$

where $A_{n,k}(x)$ and $B_{n,k}(x)$ are polynomials, we have

$$
A_{n,k}(x) = \operatorname{Re} P_{n,k}(x) \qquad \text{and} \qquad B_{n,k}(x) = \operatorname{Im}\, P_{n,k}(x).
$$

---

The first few polynomials $P_{n,k}(x)$ are

$$
\begin{align}
P_{1,k}(x) &= 1-i k x \\
P_{2,k}(x) &= 2 i+2 k x-i k^2 x^2 \\
P_{3,k}(x) &= -6+6 i k x+3 k^2 x^2-i k^3 x^3 \\
P_{4,k}(x) &= -24 i-24 k x+12 i k^2 x^2+4 k^3 x^3-i k^4 x^4 \\
P_{5,k}(x) &= 120-120 i k x-60 k^2 x^2+20 i k^3 x^3+5 k^4 x^4-i k^5 x^5 \\
P_{6,k}(x) &= 720 i+720 k x-360 i k^2 x^2-120 k^3 x^3+30 i k^4 x^4+6 k^5 x^5-i k^6 x^6 \\
P_{7,k}(x) &= -5040+5040 i k x+2520 k^2 x^2-840 i k^3 x^3-210 k^4 x^4+42 i k^5 x^5+7 k^6 x^6-i k^7 x^7
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for spending the time to look at this.

Comment: Did you mean that $F_{n,k}(x) = x^{n} e^{ikx}$?

Comment: @Frank, Sure thing :).  And no, I meant the integral of that.  Or did I make a typo somewhere?

Comment: Not sure... $F_{n,k}(x)=\int_{0}^{x} u^n e^{i k u}\,du$ ?

Comment: @Frank, I meant $\int x^n e^{i k x}\,dx$ as an indefinite integral, evaluated by repeated integration by parts (keep differentiating the $x^n$ and integrating the $e^{ikx}$), so that $$\begin{align} \int e^{ikx}\,dx &= -\frac{ie^{ikx}}{k}, \\ \int x e^{ikx}\,dx &= \frac{e^{i k x} (1-i k x)}{k^2}, \\ \int x^2 e^{ikx}\,dx &= \frac{e^{i k x} \left(2 i+2 k x-i k^2 x^2\right)}{k^3}, \\ \int x^3 e^{ikx}\,dx &= \frac{e^{i k x} \left(-6+6 i k x+3 k^2 x^2-i k^3 x^3\right)}{k^4},\end{align}$$ etc.

Comment: To derive the recurrence relation, try $u = x^n e^{ikx}$ and $dv = dx$.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are doing, my objection was only with the "syntax" of $F_{n,k}(x) = \int x^n e^{i k x}\,dx$. For me personally, having "the same" $x$ show on both sides of this equality is kind of puzzling, because $\int_{a}^{b} x^n e^{i k x}\,dx$ is not a function of $x$ after integration

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at, but that little abuse of notation is standard, and here $x$ is treated as a formal variable rather than a number.  The $\int \cdots dx$ is just the antiderivative operator, and the $+C$ usually associated with the operation is taken to be $0$.  It's not a definite integral.

Comment: @Frank, I did some thinking and you could use a definite integral instead, namely $F_{n,k}(x) = \int_{i\infty}^{x} u^n e^{iku}\,du$ with the path of integration coming down the imaginary axis from $i\infty$ to the origin, then moving along the real axis to $x$.  But really the path of integration isn't that important, and this definite integral can be evaluated formally with the fundamental theorem.

Comment: Of course now you run into the problem that the integral $\int_{i\infty}^{x} u^n \cos(kx)\,dx$ is no longer the real part of $F_{n,k}(x)$, since it doesn't even converge.

Answer (score 3):

You could also consider the exponential generating function
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{t^n}{n!} \int_0^x s^n e^{iks}\ ds = \int_0^x e^{(t+ik)s}\ ds = \dfrac{e^{(t+ik)x} - 1}{t+ik}$$
This is the product of $e^{(t+ik)x}-1 = -1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{t^n x^n}{n!} e^{ikx}$ and $\dfrac{1}{t+ik} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \dfrac{t^n}{(ik)^{n+1}}$, so 
$$\int_0^x s^n e^{iks}\ ds = n! \left(\dfrac{1}{(-ik)^{n+1}} + \sum_{j=0}^n e^{ikx} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-j}}{j! (ik)^{n-j+1}} x^j\right)$$